# Switching to an alert and accepting it with selenium does not work anymore

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, alert

Some time ago, I was using Selenium in order to scrape information from a website. Randomly, a pop-up message appeared. At that time I was able to bypass it really easy, using EC imported like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

The alert that is blocking me looks like this:
[image: Alert]

This is the piece of code that worked for me at that time:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
time.sleep(2)
alert.accept()
```

But now, coming back to this script it seems that is not working anymore. Since this pop up is also blocking me from inspecting the page source, I don't know what else to try anymore.

Comment: What error do you see on the console? Also, worth trying increasing the timeout duration from `3s` to perhaps more, say `10s`

Comment: I am not seing any error. It just doesn’t do anything. My script is supposed to navigate from one page to another but it just sticks on this one because of the alert. But I will try increasing the time :)

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example